# In an Integral Domain, if $a^2=1$, then $a=1$ or $a=-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I can't think of a way to prove this, can anyone help?

EDIT: I noticed this is a really simple question, and the confusion I made came from not seeing what was false intuition and what was the real Algebraic structure I was studying, I'm just starting to learn Algebra. Thanks for the answers, and sorry for those who thought my question didn't follow the standards it should have, I really didn't mean to cause this negative impact.

Comment: What you can't think of? Didn't occur to you to use the definition of integral domain? Stop being lazy and do your own homework.

Comment: Hey Xam, why so angry man? In here people just ask questions and if anyone is willing to help (so it's their own choice) they help. I didn't want to make you angry, I'm really sorry. After I received the answer of the problem I noticed it was simple, but I'm just starting to learn Abstract Algebra and sometimes it's difficult to separate my intuition, which comes from dealing with real numbers, from the general structures of algebra, which are not always intuitive. I hope you understand me, I didn't mean to cause a negative impact on the forum with this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a^2-1=0$ is equivalent to $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)=0$ since the domain is integral, $a=1$ or $a=-1$.

Comment: "since the domain is integral" isn't very useful, since the word does not contribute as much as "domain." It's the domain part that says something about zero divisors. It would be more sensical to say "since this is an integral domain, one of the two is zero."

Answer (score 3):

For added insight, let's do a slightly more general case. We prove that a nonzero quadratic polynomial $f(x)$ over a domain $D$ has at most two roots $\,\color{#c00}{a\neq b},\,$ by using the Factor Theorem twice, and using that $D$ is a domain, so a product of nonzero elements remains nonzero.

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\:f(b)= 0 &\ \Rightarrow\ &\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ g\in D[x]\\
\rm f(a) = (\color{#C00}{a\!-\!b})\,g(a) = 0 &\Rightarrow&\rm g(a)\, =\, 0\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in F[x]\\
&\Rightarrow&\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!b)(x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\end{eqnarray}$

Comparing degree shows $h(x) = c$ is constant, and $f\neq 0\,\Rightarrow\,c\neq 0.\,$ If $f$ had a third  root $r$ then $(r\!-\!b)(r\!-\!a)c = 0$, contra each factor is nonzero hence so is their product, since $D$ is a domain.

**Remark** $ $ The proof immediately generalizes by induction to yield that a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots over a domain. In fact this is a *characteristic property* of domains, since if $R$ is not a domain then there are $a,b\neq 0$ with $\,ab = 0\,$ so $\,f = ax\,$ has $2$ roots, $\,x = 0,b.$